# Call api with dual authentication with restsharp

Tags: c#, api, authorization, restsharp

I'm brand new to restsharp and somewhat new to c#
I am trying to use restsharp to access an api.

With powershell I can use.

```
$ClientCredsPlainText   = $ClientID + ":" + $ClientSecret
$ClientCredsBase64      = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($ClientCredsPlainText))
 
$AuthHeader = @{"Content-Type"  = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                "accept"        = 'application/json'
                "authorization" = "Basic $ClientCredsBase64" }
$AuthAPI    = @{"endpoint"      = 'https://foo.bar.com/api/'
                "url"           = '/now/table/cmdb_ci_server?u_owner_group=' }
$AuthBody   = @{"grant_type"    = 'password'
                "username"      = $SessionUser
                "password"      = $SessionPassword }

$finalresult=@()
$mdsownergroup=@('foo','bar','foofoo','barbar')
foreach ($item in $mdsownergroup) {
    $cmdburi        = $AuthAPI.endpoint + $AuthAPI.url + $item
    $cmdbrequest    = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $cmdburi -Headers $AuthHeader -Body $AuthBody 
    $finalresult+=$cmdbrequest.result 
    }
$cmdbrequest.result
```

I am trying the same thing in c# with restsharp and postman suggests the following should work.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://foo.bar.com/api/");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("X-IBM-Client-Id", "xxxxxx");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "[{\"key\":\"\",\"value\":\"xxxxxx",\"description\":\"\",\"type\":\"text\",\"enabled\":true}]");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic xxxx");
request.AddHeader("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=xxxxx glide_user_route=glide.xxxx glide_session_store=xxxx; BIGipServerpool_foo=209737994.35390.0000");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

Using this I receive:

```
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You mention you are "doing the same thing" but the second piece of code does not appear to be reflective of the first one. Please avoid posting "simplified versions". Small reproducible samples are fine, but they must contain everything needed for us to be able to help you.

Comment: I guess to be more clear. I believe I am doing the same thing.  This is the powershell code that I am using and the c# as suggested by postman.

Comment: Got it. The PowerShell version is adding a password grant with credentials. I don't see that anywhere in the C# version. I also don't see any cookies in the PowerShell version.

Comment: I spotted something else. I think you want to do a POST, not a GET.

Comment: See the answer. below. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually after reviewing with another dev it turns out I needed to use basic auth and remove the username and password.  That is I over complicated by passing both client id and secret as well as username and password.